# Protocols var {get}

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Whenever a protocol is declared with a var with a getter only I thought that would mean that the var would be settable from inside the class and not from the outside since there is no "setter".

Playground code

```
protocol RunningAnimal{
    var limbs:Int { get }
    var topSpeed:Int{ get }
}

class Cheetah:RunningAnimal {
    var limbs = 4
    var topSpeed = 120
}

let cheetah = Cheetah()
cheetah.limbs = 100
print("cheetah limbs ->\(cheetah.limbs)") //prints 100
```

Whats the point of declaring {get} if you can still change its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RunningAnimal` makes a positive promise: you must provide getters for a `limbs` property and a `topSpeed` property. It does not make any "negative promises." It doesn't say that you *can't* provide a setter for these properties. You can provide any other methods or accessors you want.

That said, the protocol here is pretty much irrelevant. `cheetah` is of type `Cheetah`, and `Cheetah` has an internally available setter on `limbs`.

If you changed this code to use the protocol type, then you would be restricted to what the protocol promises:

```
let cheetah: RunningAnimal = Cheetah()
cheetah.limbs = 100 // error: cannot assign to property: 'limbs' is a get-only property
```

In your particular example, you should almost certainly just make `limbs` a `let` variable. You are free to use a `let` to fulfill a `var {get}` promise:

```
class Cheetah: RunningAnimal {
    let limbs = 4
    let topSpeed = 120
}

let cheetah = Cheetah()
cheetah.limbs = 100 // error: cannot assign to property: 'limbs' is a 'let' constant
```

In the more general case where you want the property to be privately writable, you can just mark the setter private:

```
class Cheetah: RunningAnimal {
    let limbs = 4
    private(set) var topSpeed = 120
}
```

You even could make your properties computed, and still conform to `RunningAnimal`:

```
class Cheetah: RunningAnimal {
    var limbs: Int { return 4 }
    var topSpeed: Int { return 120 }
}
```

Protocols don't really care how you implement properties, as long as you provide a getter and setter as required. (This doesn't apply to functions. Protocol function requirements must be implemented as a method. They cannot be implemented as a closure property of the same type.)

Answer (score 0):

The default access for vars is internal so you should change it to private to prevent anything from outside changing it if that's what you wanted.

The protocol itself though is only requiring to have a computed property that returns something.  It's only telling you to create something that returns an Int.  there are a few ways to satisfy that requirement.

You could of created a getter with the name limbs and then have an internal property that can't be changed from the outside.

```
 var limbs:Int { 
         return _limbs
 }
```

And _limbs itself is private

```
 private var _limbs:Int
```

Comment: If you just want to provide a public getter and private setter, there's no need for the private backing var / computed getter approach. Just use the `private(set)` access modifier.

Comment: @rickster I mentioned there were different ways to do it, I was trying to answer his question without too much confusion, however looks like Rob Napier said it more eloquently that I could